# php I need to write a json_encode function equivalent

Tags: php

I'm trying to use webspace provided by my university.  They are currently using an outdated version of php, 5.1 I think.  Anyway it doesn't have a json_encode function, however, I need a json_encode function (or equivalent) for my code to work.

So if anyone could explain to me the syntax for the return of the json_encode function or point me to a website that explains it nicely it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel: [upgrade.php library](http://upgradephp.berlios.de/).

Answer (score 2):

http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON

Answer (score 2):

Check [here](http://www.boutell.com/scripts/jsonwrapper.html).  It tells you to use `require 'jsonwrapper.php';` at the start of your code in versions of PHP where `json_encode` is not available.